Double tax treaty US-UK for UK resident
I want to understand if I'll pay taxes to the UK on my foreign income earned in the US and if the current tax treaty allows me to be exempt. Next is my understanding, and I'd like to know if it is correct.
I'm a tax resident in the UK for the 24-25 tax year. During that tax year, I'll do a three-month internship in the US for PhD students at a company, and I'll be hired as an employee during those months. This income will be taxed in the US at source.
In the same tax year, I will be employed in the UK until the internship starts. These two will be my only sources of income during the tax year.
I understand that I must complete the UK Self Assessment, report both incomes and claim tax relief credits on the taxes paid in the US. This relief will compare the taxes paid in the US and the UK, for such foreign income, and the relief is equal to the one that is the least. Assuming that the taxes paid in the US will be the lowest, I am still due to pay taxes on my foreign income in the UK.
To provide more context, I can't apply to a split-year treatment since I was a UK tax resident in the previous tax year, and I'll be one in the following. Also, my salary in the UK already exceeds my personal allowance.
Thanks in advance.

Nit: US FICA tax (roughly UK's NI) is largely collected at source for employees (there are some exceptions) but as a foreign student you are exempt from FICA for several years. (Make sure your employer's HR dept knows this; if they wrongly apply FICA to you, it will be a hassle to get it back.) US also requires employers to 'withhold' for federal=national income tax, but this is only an estimate that is almost never exact, so everyone (except the very poor) files a 'return' (i.e. an assessment) to compare actual tax to withholding, and either post-pay or get back the difference. ...

... Most but not all US states also have an income tax with a similar withholding-then-reconciliation scheme, although I believe some of the simpler state schemes now have prefilled/default returns. So do a fairly small number of cities.

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your answer. I think you are correct regarding the US taxes. Just in case, my main concern is whether my foreign income is still taxable under UK law.
